# NFS Share Volume wont mount to Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nfs

I am trying to mount an NFS share inside a docker container. I am using docker compose and my compose file is as follows:

```
version: "3.2"

volumes:
  movies:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: nfs
      o: addr=mediaserver,nfsvers=4,nolock,soft,rw
      device: :/media/movies

services:
  radarr:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/radarr:latest
    container_name: radarr
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=America/Toronto
    volumes:
      - /home/tom/docker/configs/radarr:/config
      - movies:/movies
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - medianet
    ports:
      - 7878:7878
```

When I run docker compose, I get an error stating:

```
Error response from daemon: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/docker_movies/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount :/media/movies:/var/lib/docker/volumes/docker_movies/_data, data: addr=192.168.0.62,nfsvers=4,nolock,soft: no such file or directory
```

Now my first thought was I had entered the path incorrectly, but If I try this on the docker host it mounts fine and I can see the files inside the mount.

This is the command I use to mount it directly on the host:

```
sudo mount -t nfs mediaserver:/media/movies /home/tom/testmoviemount
```

I feel like I must be doing something wrong, I just can't seem to find what as I am so new. Hope someone has some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I runned same docker-compose file without network medianet and services worked well,

[image]

I only changed the local path to mines in:

```bash
#docker-compose.yml
...
    volumes:
      - /home/tom/docker/configs/radarr:/config
      - movies:/movies
...
```

Just make sure the paths `/home/tom/docker/configs/radarr` and `movies` are correct and exist locally.

Now, when putting a wrong local path in docker-compose file, I get following error:

```bash
Creating radarr ... error

ERROR: for radarr  Cannot start service radarr: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/00_docker_movies/_data': error resolving passed in network volume address: lookup mediaserver on XXX.XXX.XX.X:XX: no such host
```

which is the same as yours `error while mounting volume..`

Comment: Thankyou for testing, however I think it has some other issue. I am able to run radarr just fine if I use a local folder mount, but I want to use the volume I created earlier. I think there is something wrong with how I create the NFS volume.